# Web worker inside Web worker possible?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

im trying to spawn a web worker inside a web worker but im getting this error:

> mainWorker.js:92 Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined

using this code:

```
var worker = new Worker('subWorker.js');
worker.postMessage(......);
```

is this possible in some way??

Comment: You could message the main thread to spawn another Worker thread.

Comment: oh I didn't think about it.... ill try

Comment: It should actually work, but it [doesn’t work in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666) and Safari yet. You could try the “detour” over the main thread as a work-around.

Comment: @Vanojx1 It works now.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who stumbles here, nested workers now have some support in Chrome at least: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6080438103703552:

> Dedicated workers can create nested workers, but shared workers and
>   service workers cannot.
>
> Creating a nested dedicated worker from a shared worker is not yet
>   supported.
>
> Nested shared workers are also in the spec, but there is no plan to
>   support them at this time.

Comment: Creating a Worker from an audio worklet does not work though.